# Cannot use Faye locally anylonger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, faye

I'm used to start the Faye server on my local environment using

```
sudo bundle exec rackup faye.ru -s thin -E production
```

and it was working fine. But now I don't know what happened, and whenewer I try it i get this error:

> /Users/.../.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in
>   `to_specs': Could not find bundler (>= 0) amongst [bigdecimal-1.1.0,
>   io-console-0.3, json-1.5.4, minitest-2.5.1, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-3.9.4]
>   (Gem::LoadError)

I'm 100% sure bundler is installed, and I also tried to run `gem install bundler`, which reinstall bundler, but nothing changes.

Any guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working using

```
rackup faye.ru -s thin -E production
```